# ng-if in ng-repeat recreating elements on click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, if-statement, dom

I wanted to replace anchor tag by img when user clicked on it.
My Sample code is like

```
<div ng-repeat="postpart in currentPost.parts ">



   <div ng-if = "!postpart.isclicked">
          <img ng-src="{{imgurl}}" ng-click="iclicked(postpart)"/>
   </div>

   <div ng-if = "postpart.isclicked">
       <a ng-href="{{postpart.description}}" ng-init="init()"></a>
   </div>



</div>
```

iclicked function just make isclicked to true.

It worked perfectly for one part. 
But When there are 2 parts it is showing 2 images.
When i click on first it replaces by one anchor element.

But in case of 2nd image click it replaces with 2 anchor tags.

How can i able to make it?
is there any solution to replace image element by anchor in ng-repeat?

Comment: you should try `ng-hide`, `ng-show`

Comment: Thing is i wanted to replace element..

Comment: can you provide http://jsfiddle.net link ?

Comment: Please provide a full working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be help you.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.parts = [
    {"description": "This is a test","isclicked":false,"type":"MEDIA"},
    {"description": "This is a test2","isclicked":false,"type":"MEDIA"},
    {"description": "This is a test3","isclicked":false,"type":"MEDIA"},
    {"description": "This is a test4","isclicked":false,"type":"MEDIA"}
  
  ];
    
  $scope.iclicked = function(index){
    $scope.parts[index].isclicked = !$scope.parts[index].isclicked;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">  
  <div ng-repeat="part in parts">
    <div ng-show = "!part.isclicked">
      <img src="/images/1.png" ng-click="iclicked($index)"/>
    </div>

    <div ng-show = "part.isclicked">
      <a href="part.description" >{{part.description}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```